# Problems entering information in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

I'm trying to introduce some data info in the DB on production mode but is not working I'm using PDO for the connection to the DB, in my localhost works correctly but in the GoDaddy server isn't.

I'm using MVC, when I submit I send the data by POST and in the controller is like this

when i make a submit i execute this

```php
    $Registro = new ControladorUsuarios();
    $Registro -> ctrRegistroUsuario();
```

```php
static public function ctrRegistroUsuario(){



    if (isset($_POST["regUsuario"])) {
        if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.]+$/', $_POST["regUsuario"]) &&
          preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $_POST["regEmail"]) &&
          preg_match('/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]+$/', $_POST["regPassword"])) {

          $encriptar = crypt($_POST["regPassword"], '//hash');

          $encriptarEmail = md5($_POST["regEmail"]);

          $datos = array(
            "usuario" => strtolower($_POST["regUsuario"]),
            "email" => strtolower($_POST["regEmail"]),
            "password" => $encriptar,
            "nombre" => strtolower($_POST["regNombre"]),
            "apellidos" => strtolower($_POST["regApellido"]),
            "telefono" => $_POST["regTelefono"],
            "verificacion" => $encriptarEmail
          );

          $tabla = "usuario";

          $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlRegistroUsuario($tabla, $datos);

          if ($respuesta == "ok") {

            /*===================================================================
            =            HERE I SEND A CONFIRMATION MAIL ACCOUNT           =
            ===================================================================*/

            $envio = $mail->Send();

            if (!$envio) {

              echo'error';

            } else {

              echo 'success';

            }

          }else{

            echo 'error2';

          }

        }
      }

    }
```

when i make a submit the error goes to error2 and in my model i have this

```php
    public static function mdlRegistroUsuario($tabla, $datos){

      $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, email, password, nombre, apellidos, telefono, verificacion) VALUES (:usuario, :email, :password, :nombre, :apellidos, :telefono, :verificacion)");

      $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datos["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

      $stmt->bindParam(":email", $datos["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

      $stmt->bindParam(":password", $datos["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

      $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

      $stmt->bindParam(":apellidos", $datos["apellidos"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

      $stmt->bindParam(":telefono", $datos["telefono"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

      $stmt->bindParam(":verificacion", $datos["verificacion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

      if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return "ok";
      } else {
        return errorinfo();
      }

      $stmt->close();

      $stmt = null;

    }
```

In my `error_log` appears this errors

```
    #0 route/Controladores/usuarios.controlador.php(33): ModeloUsuarios::mdlRegistroUsuario('usuario', Array)
    #1 route/registro.php(42): ControladorUsuarios::ctrRegistroUsuario()
    #5 {main}
      thrown in route/Modelos/usuarios.modelo.php on line 31
```

I really don't know what the problem is hope someone can help me

Comment: What you post here is the stacktrace of the error, you should have an error message before that, can you also add that to the question?

Comment: @catcon I'm sorry but it doesn't print another error, that's why I can't understand the error, much less know what it is

Comment: Well, for starters, `ctrRegistroUsuario` is marked as a `static` method but you're calling it like an instance method